# Test a list type data in Decision Table

Tags: drools, rules, dmn

I am trying to use a create a rule using a list type data in Drools.

I want to provide a list of numbers as an input data, and test it whether it contains a certain number in a decision table.

As in the following images, I created a input data, IntegerArr, and a decision table. Custom data type, IntegerArr, is defined as a list type of number.

I would like to get a result true, testing my input data which is ArrayList type data, Java.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr.add(1);
arr.add(2);

Hashmap input = new HashMap();
input.put("IntegerArr", arr);
```

[image: DRD]

[image: DecisionTable with Integer Array as an input]

If I call a dmn function, `list contains(IntegerArr, 1)`, as a result, it returns `true` which means the function is called without any problem.

But when I use it in the when statement, it seems to not pass, even though its result is true.

**Additional Case - Success**

This is the success case, which the primitive data type is used as an input data.

[image: DecisitonTable with String data as an input]

I am running a rule with an input data, `groupName`, with a string data, `"javaClass"`.

If I write the same FEEL logic with String type input data, it passes the rule and gives the correct result.

I would like to know how to write a rule in a when column of decision table, using a list type data.